# How to prove a bounded linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

I need to prove that $B \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ when $D \subset X$ is a dense subspace and $A \in \mathcal{L}(D,Y)$ is some bounded linear operator from $D$ to $Y$ when we assume that $Y$ is a Banach space.

My approach was to show that B is a bounded linear operator, if it satisfies:

i) $A(\alpha x_n)=\alpha A(x_n) \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{K} $

and

ii) $A(x_n + x_m) = A(x_n) + A(x_m)$

I started to feel pretty lost since this is an introduction to real analysis course, so please correct me if I'm wrong in approaching this problem. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any relationship between $A$ and $B$.  Do you mean that $A$ is a restriction of $B$ to the set $D$?

Comment: My bad, this is a sup-problem, which helps us prove the main problem, which is to prove that there is a unique $B \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ such that $Ax = Bx$ for every $x \in D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is that if $A = B|_D$ then prove that $B$ is bounded.  Let $x \in X\setminus D$ and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $D$ such that $x_n \to x$.  Then compute the following limit:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} ||Bx - Bx_n|| & = & \lim_{n\to\infty} ||Bx - Ax_n|| \\
 & = & \lim_{n\to\infty} ||Bx - Bx_n + Bx_n - Ax_n|| \\
& \leq & \lim_{n\to\infty} ||B(x-x_n)|| + ||Bx_n - Ax_n||.
\end{eqnarray*}

Notice that the above limit must be zero since $x-x_n \to 0$ and $By = Ay$ for each $y \in D$.  This proves that $B$ is continuous, and is therefore bounded.

Comment: Doesn't the continuous function $B$ have to be in a closed interval in order to be bounded?